# Facebook Apps Do Not Show in one Page's Sidebar but Do Show on Another

Tags: facebook

I have 2 iframe apps I am developing for a client.  I have added them to the client's page and also to mine.

The apps show in the sidebar on [my page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/NolaFlashcom/39872648066). But they have never shown up on the [client page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Gulf-Coast-Bank-Trust-Co/129689329517?ref=ts) sidebar.  The apps cannot be seen on the client's page even if I copy the query string ?sk=app_203422409706573 from my URL into theirs

When I access as admin and go to the apps list for the pages I see a slight difference:

MY PAGE (shows "link to this tab" link)

[image: my page]

THEIR PAGE (does not show "link to this tab")

[image: their page]

Does anyone know why they aren't showing on the bank page?  I'm an admin both places, though I am the only admin on mine and one of three on theirs.

One other note is that I don't yet have the SSL for the canvas page but I am not browsing is secure mode and they apps still don't show up in the sidebar.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially clicking "Edit Settings" had resulted in a message that no settings were available.

After the Tab URL and Tab Name values propagated the link offers "Tab:  Available (add)"

Once added the "Link to this tab" link is visible.